# How can I share a Google Drive file to anyone on iOS?

Tags: ios, permission, file-sharing, google-apps, google-docs

On iPhone/iOS, is it possible to share a Google doc (or for that matter, any file on Google Drive) with *anyone* who has the link provided by the "Link Sharing" feature?

I AM able to share with other people *who are using my domain/are part of my G Suite*.

What I do NOT see is how I can share a file with *anyone* who has the link.

[image: cannot change to anyone access]

I CAN perform this task in the web interface, under "Advanced"..

[image: the web interface works and is easy]

but **cannot find similar functionality in the mobile app**.

Answer (score 1):

If you're the G Suite administrator, you can control whether users can share their Drive files outside your organization. You can also set the default sharing options for new files created by users.

To allow users to share outside your organization to anyone:

1. Sign in to your **Google Admin console**.
2. From the Admin console dashboard, go to **Apps > G Suite > Drive and Docs**.
3. Click **Sharing settings**.
4. Under **Sharing outside of *organization***, select **ON**. Users can invite people outside the organization to view, comment on, and edit their files.
5. Select the options according to what you need.

You can fine tune the sharing settings. Read more at the [G Suite docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60781).

Comment: That turns the link on for anyone in our org, not for the world.

Comment: @AndrewWarner Are you the G Suite administrator?

Comment: Yes @DakshShah. Is there something I can do as an admin?

Comment: @AndrewWarner Edited my original answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question:

> On iPhone/iOS, is it possible to share a Google doc (or for that matter, any file on Google Drive) with anyone who has the link provided by the "Link Sharing" feature?

Looking at [the official docs](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en) it does appear that you can share a link from within the Google Drive app.

### Sharing folders section from the docs

[image: ss1]

### Sharing files section from the docs

[image: ss2]

#### References

- [Share files from Google Drive - folder section](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822#link_sharing)
- [Sharing files from Google Drive - files section](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=1)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be applicable to users in G Suite organisations on the iOS app, even where the org permits sharing outside the org.

Comment: @markd - not sure what to say, don't have either of this and the official docs seem to imply you can.

Comment: for non-org accounts your answer works fine. For an org account of mine, I solved this by using my mobile browser in "desktop mode" and setting the link sharing settings as per desktop.

Comment: You can't share publicly from the iOS app... You HAVE to go to the website. Google client-facing tech get's more disappointing every day.